# Probability measure on the Rationals. density function, and integration?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Nornally, we define a probability space on the continuum, the real numbers.

For simplicity, lets say we have a "flat distribution" on $[0,1]\subset \mathbb R$. Then the measure of the rationals $[0,1]\subset \mathbb Q$  is zero.

But what if we instead define the measure only on the rationals? That is, for any set containing only irrationals, that sets measure is zero. And the measure of $ [0,1]\cap \mathbb Q$ is 1.

1. Can we define, without problems, the same density function on [0,1] as we would if we were using the real numbers?
2. Can we define the cumulative distribution function in the same way, without problems?
3. Does this in any other way generate pathologies? Or is it legitimate?

Comment: I don't quite follow you. Any set containing only irrationals has measure $0$? But then $[0,1]\setminus\mathbb Q$ has measure $0$. Not $1$ as you assert.

Comment: @drhab, you're thinking of the lebesgue measure. I'm talking about defining a probability measure that only has positive measure on sets of rationals. (Or alternatively, is only dedined on the rationals)

Comment: So by "the sets measure" you meant the Lebesgue measure.  Am I understanding correct?

Comment: @drhab, woops mistype. Its fixed now.

Comment: $[0,1]\setminus\mathbb R=\varnothing$ so I guess you fixed wrongly.

Comment: Measure of  $[0,1]/\mathbb R$ is 1 which is basically empty set. Do you mean rationals in $[0,1]$?

Comment: @drhab, lol sorry.. too hasty. Fixed again.

Answer (score 3):

A probability measure $\mathsf P$ on $\langle\mathbb R^n,\mathcal B^n\rangle$ will only have a *[probability density function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function)* if it is *[absolutely continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity#Definition_2)* wrt the Lebesgue measure.

That is, if:  $$\lambda(B)=0\implies\mathsf P(B)=0$$ for any measurable set $B$, where $\lambda$ denotes the Lebesgue measure.

Note that this is a necessary condition simply because: $$\lambda(B)=0\implies\mathsf P(B)= \int_Bf(x)\lambda(dx)=0$$ for any probability density $f$ of $\mathsf P$.

We have $\lambda([0,1]\cap\mathbb Q)=0$ so if $\mathsf P([0,1]\cap\mathbb Q)=1$ then no density wrt the Lebesgue measure exists.

In that situation a so-called *[probability mass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_mass_function)* comes in.

On $[0,1]\cap\mathbb Q$ we have the *[counting measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_measure)* sending every set $A\subseteq[0,1]\cap\mathbb Q$ to its cardinality in $\{0,1,2,\dots\}\cup\{\infty\}$. In this situation the probability measure is absolutely continuous wrt to the counting measure and also has a density wrt that measure.

This is a function $p:[0,1]\cap\mathbb Q\to[0,\infty)$ such that $P(A)=\sum_{a\in A}p(a)$ for every $A\subseteq[0,1]\cap\mathbb Q$.

It is more common to define it as a function $\mathbb R\to[0,\infty)$ such that can only take positive values on elements in $[0,1]\cap\mathbb Q$.

So $p$ is somehow a density (wrt counting measure) but is not a density wrt the Lebesgue measure. It never gets the label PDF but it gets the label PMF.

Comment: yes I guessed something like this. It should be the Radon Nikodym derivative of the probability measure I set up w.r.t. the counting measure? But what I find weird is, that every time I have seen it so far, a PMF has positive values for single elements. E.g. the binomial distribution is defined on $\bb N$, and has positive value for some $n$. But the measure I defined, doesn't have positive measure at any individual $q\in\bb Q$. Thats why I thought, maybe its density will be "something in between a PDF and PMF".

Comment: Are you saying that the measure $P$ that you defined on $[0,1]\cap\mathbb Q$ takes value $0$ for every singleton $\{q\}\subseteq[0,1]\cap\mathbb Q$? If so then $P([0,1]\cap Q)=\sum_{q\in[0,1]\cap\mathbb Q}P(\{q\})=0\neq1$. Every PMF $p$ must satisfy $\sum_{x\in X}p(x)=1$ for some countable set $X$ so it is unavoidable that it takes positive values on some of the $x\in X$.

Comment: Hmm yes you are right. Perhaps the only way to make this work would be to loosen the axiom of additivity to merely finite additivity. Is there a concept of a "pseudomeasure" or something, where the axiom of countable additivity is loosened to finite additivity?

Comment: Not that I know of, and also I don't see a solution in that direction.  Mainly because I don't see what you are really after. I am unable to form a picture of the meaning of "this" in your former comment.

Comment: its very simple. I simply want a probability " measure" on the set of rationals in (0,1) such that the probability of $(a,b)\cap \bb Q$ equals b-a. It is simply the flat distribution but restrictes to the rationals. Intuitively, it should capture the idea that "each rational is equally likely to occur", even though there are an infinite amount of them. Similar to how the flat diatribution on the reals captures the idea that "each real number is equally likely to occur". Why do I wonder about this? Purely theoretical interest

Comment: Sorry to disappoint you then. Such "flat" probability measure on $[0,1]\cap\mathbb Q$ does not exist. Suppose it does exists. Then for every element $q$ we must have the **same** value $P(\{q\})$. Both options ($P(\{q\})=0$ and $P(\{q\})>0$) lead to a contradiction. In both cases we have $P([0,1]\cap\mathbb Q)=\sum_{q\in[0,1]\cap\mathbb Q}P(\{q\})$. In the first case that leads to $P([0,1]\cap\mathbb Q)=0$ and in the second that leads to $P([0,1]\cap\mathbb Q)=+\infty$. So both contradict the necessary $P([0,1]\cap\mathbb Q)=1$.

Comment: this aegument doesn't convince me. You could have made the same argument against probability measures on real numbers, until you've invented the integral. I think we could just define a limit process to define such a probability "pseudomeasure". A PDF is also nothing more than such  a limiting process. I will try to define this later when I have time.

Comment: First let me speak out my admiration for your determination and willingness to "out of the box thinking". Each rational equally likely to occur demands that the probability of occurring $q$ is zero. This allready by additivity  (as it also is for the reals in $[0,1]$ if the distribution is uniform). If you manage  to find such "pseudo-measure" then automatically you are able to project it on well-ordered sets like $\mathbb N$. This implicates that - turning the route around - you should also be able to do it starting at $\mathbb N$.

Comment: A uniform (pseudo)-measure on $\mathbb N$. Wow,... I am looking forward to it. Good luck with this (I really mean that), and keep me informed of any progress in this please.

Comment: How about pseudo-measure $\mu$ on the subsets of $\mathbb Q$ defined by $\mu(A)=\lambda(\overline A)$ where $\overline A$ denotes the closure of $A\subseteq\mathbb Q\subseteq R$ according to the usual topology on $\mathbb R$ and where $\lambda$ denotes the Lebesgue measure. No additivity though and heavily depending on the context provided by $\mathbb R$. However, it obeys $\mu((a,b)\cap Q)=b-a$ which is one of your aims.